# Warning: React does not recognize the `computedMatch` prop on a DOM element. This is the error I am getting in my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
Warning: React does not recognize the `computedMatch` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `computedmatch` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    at div
    at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38973:29)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38402:30)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38024:35)
    at NoteState (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1041:76)
    at div
    at App
```

I am using bootstap, but I don't think it has anything to do with this error. Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: the error, and solution are spelled out for you

Answer (score -2):

There is a tip for new beginners like you: Look at the error given, try to figure out what exactly the error is saying. Mostly you will get solutions from errors.

---

Here, the Solution is given in the error statement.